# require("ssh2") without specific object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

What does it mean if you `require('ssh2')` in Node.js without a specific object (e.g. `require('ssh2').Client`)?  I have some code I am trying to understand and I am just learning Node.js.  It's used like this:

```
var ssh2Connection = require("ssh2");
...
var conn new ssh2Connection();
conn.on("ready", function() {
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Requiring require("ssh2") is essentially returning the value defined by this line

```
module.exports = 'hello'
```

Requiring require("ssh2").Client is essentially returning the value defined by this line

```
module.exports.Client = 'hello'
```

This is used to extend multiple objects to a module. Could be something like

```
module.exports.Client1 = 'hello1'
module.exports.Client2 = 'hello2'
```

Comment: Is it using Client?  There are multiple exports in [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/tree/master/lib).  How does it decide which one to use if you don't specify a specific object?